# how to use an stl algo on a container of variants

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda, c++17, variant

I have a container of variants. There are 3 different types in 
the container that share the same interface. I want to use 
certain algos like find_if and accumulate.

```
    struct Type1{bool hasField(const string& name)const{return false;}};
    struct Type2{bool hasField(const string& name)const{return false;}};
    struct Type3{bool hasField(const string& name)const{return true;}};
    struct Type4{bool hasField(const string& name)const{return false;}}; 

    auto cont = vector<variant<Type1,Type2,Type3>>{Type1{},Type3{},Type2{}};

    string name{"field1"};

     //each type has hasField member.
    auto it = find_if(begin(cont), end(cont), [&name](const auto& field)
              {std::visit([](const auto& arg){return arg.hasField(name);}, field);});

      //another ex:

      return std::accumulate(begin(m_fields), end(m_fields), 0, 
           [](size_t tot, const auto& field){
              visit([&](const auto& f){return tot += f.getSize();}, field);});


          linux-gnu/include/c++/8.3.0/bits/predefined_ops.h:283:11: error: 
           void value not ignored as it ought to be
            { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
```

can someone show me what the correct syntax is for this?
I tried to google around but didn't find any examples.

Comment: ?? Could you give complete code? The classes don't have a member function getSize. And what's wrong with good old polymorphism?

Comment: `return` is missing `return std::visit()...`, also most inner lambda should capture `name`.

Comment: thanks rafix07 that worked.

Comment: JHBonarius : 1) I the changed the design to use variant so I can have static  polymorphism instead of runtime. the benefits  1) No virtual table which is expensive

Comment: 2) value semantic which is what your c++ should be. 3) No pointers or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: `std::visit` might be implemented with virtual polymorphic (for the dispatching) though...

Comment: Are you sure that the "static polymorphism" really *is* a benefit? You get very much more complicated code that makes is much more unmaintainable, and the possible "efficiency" benefits have you measured those? Always go with the simple solution first, then measure and benchmark if (and only if) the program doesn't live up to the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Your first example is almost there. [This compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/jjdawX):

```
auto it = find_if(
    begin(cont),
    end(cont),
    [&name](const auto& field) {
      return std::visit(
          [&name](const auto& arg){return arg.hasField(name);}, field
      );
    }
);
```